# Automation Event not working ? C# AUTOMATION UI

Tags: c#, automation, ui-automation

I am using AUTOMATION UI and added all refrences like UIAUOMATION CLIETNT AND TYPE but my function

```
       Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
          WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
            AutomationElement.RootElement,
                    System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Subtree,
                           (sender, e) =>
                           {
                               var element = sender as AutomationElement;
                             if (element.Current.LocalizedControlType == "Dialog")
                               {

                               }
                           });

     System.Console.ReadKey();
     Automation.RemoveAllEventHandlers();
```

stops working for some dialogues like open , save , prefrences but working for others in dialogue i am registering events so it is compulsory that my events also fires for dialogue boxes point to be noted

> System.Console.Read();
>
> Automation.RemoveAllEventHandlers();

1-Above code *system.console.ReadKey();* also gives error as it is in **webservice** have no console mode

2-open and save dialogue are not detected

3-and also it is very slow

similar to that question

[link to similar problem](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1114347/Automation-event-calls-multiple-time-but-for-open)

Comment: NO AUTOMATION GURU

Answer (score -1):

Try inspecting the open/save dialogues to make sure their `localizedControlType` is what you expect.

You can use [uispy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowssdk/2008/02/18/where-is-uispy-exe/) to do this.